# Best way to implement a passcode VC lock feature? swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I'm working on my first iOS/swift app. It's a modified diary entry app, but I currently have a feature I'm trying to implement where a passcode view controller is presented if the app goes to the background (and then foreground) or is made inactive. The problem i've had is with implementation.

My question: Is there a simple way of presenting the passcodeVC on top of the current vc when it entersforeground and then dismissing it, leaving the current VC.

I understand that other view controllers can determine if the app enters foreground, but i'd imagine it's better to do it with app delegate since it seems to be the universal listener for app states. Provided i have the view controller and passcode features working, how do i get the passcode view to present itself and then dismiss if the code is correct; revealing the screen that was below it (some code would be helpful as I've spent a couple of days and it's a little over my head).

Here was an extension i tried to build:

```
public extension UIViewController {
    func show() {
        let win = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let vc = UIViewController()
        vc.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        win.rootViewController = vc
        win.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1
        win.makeKeyAndVisible()
        vc.present(self, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func hide() {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: How about you link some code. That would be a good place to start.

Comment: which code should i link? the first attempt to present the VC or the entire project on github?

Comment: Are you presenting any controller in your app on any screen?? Because you will have to track your state only for the case when application window has a view controller in presented state as only 1 VC can be presented on top of window otherwise if your app is all about navigation then you can present it with simple few lines code.

Comment: Lets start with where you're presenting and dismissing the VC. If the whole project is already up on a public github though just link that.

Comment: @DonovanKing Don't link any code. Relevant code should be put in the question, as text.

Comment: @DonovanKing https://github.com/learn-co-students/ios-team-indigo

Comment: @Ellen i linked my github source code

Comment: @BitBeast Did you see my comment? Don't post a link. [Edit] your question with minimal relevant code (as text).

Comment: @rmaddy I did not refresh in time; as far as the code goes, I don't really have a working solution for what goes in the entersforeground/background method. That's why i'm asking because after all my research on stack, i couldn't either understand the deprecated code or find an implementation to applied to my situation.